# Directly manipulating bits in assembly for bit stuffing

Tags: assembly, 32-bit, bit, insertion, bitstuffing

I am new to assembly, and I was wondering if there was a way for me to directly manipulate the bits that form a certain int value in order to simulate bit stuffing.

For example, if I have a 32bit int that represents the message I want to stuff, is there a way for me to insert a bit in the middle of that number in assembly?

Also, since the size of that int would become greater than 32, and I don't want that since the registers are 32bits, the last bits of the number will just get deleted, so no worries about that.

Comment: You have forgotten to specify what architecture, but chances are the answer is "not with a single instruction". Can be done with a few, but then you can do the same in any high level language anyway.

Comment: @Jester It's meant for Intel 32bit (80186 and higher) and I do realize I can do it in C++, but this is meant for me to understand how to use assembly, the problem being simply a pretext. So the length of the operation doesn't really matter, I am just curious if there is a way to do it.

Comment: I've worked in x86 and MIPS, and have not seen an assembly language having instructions that let you insert bits in the middle of an integer. You're best off using widely supported instructions like shift and mask.

Comment: @NayukiMinase Thank you! I guessed as much but I thought it was worth a try. So in my case there is no way to do it other than shifting the sequence to the beginning and masking the first bit to zero? I feel like it's quite heavy for such a simple operation though.

Comment: Anything you can do in C++ can be done in assembly, since C++ can be compiled to assembly (and it frequently is). Since you are not interested in the length of the operation, I wonder what your question is...

Comment: @Jester Yes building it on C++ and compiling it will work, but then I wouldn't understand how those instructions work, or even if I did, I wouldn't be the one to make them work, so it's like using a car instead of building it. Though the analogy might be a bit exaggerated ^^'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among two popular instruction set architectures I've worked with (x86 and MIPS), there are no machine instructions to insert bits into the middle of an integer like you described.

However, the functionality can be implemented in terms of bitwise shifts, AND, OR, NOT, which are available on all processors and all programming languages (such as C).

Example: Inserting 5 bits at position 12:

```
// Inputs given
uint32 original = (...);      // [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyy]
uint32 insert   = (...);      // [000000000000000000000000000zzzzz]

// Computation
uint32 mask = (1 << 12) - 1;  // [00000000000000000000111111111111]
uint32 a = original &  mask;  // [00000000000000000000yyyyyyyyyyyy]
uint32 b = original & ~mask;  // [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx000000000000]
uint32 c = b << 5;            // [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx00000000000000000]
uint32 d = b | c;             // [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx00000yyyyyyyyyyyy]
uint32 e = insert << 12;      // [000000000000000zzzzz000000000000]
uint32 result = d | e;        // [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzzzzzyyyyyyyyyyyy]

// All together compactly
uint32 result = (original & mask) | ((original & ~mask) << 5) | (insert << 12);
```